# C code to relocate the vector table

Tags: c, gcc, linker, embedded, gnu

I have following lines of code

```
#define SCB_VTOR            SCB_VTOR_REG(SystemControl_BASE_PTR)
#define SCB_VTOR_REG(base)                       ((base)->VTOR)
/* VTOR Bit Fields */
#define SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_MASK                     0xFFFFFF80u
#define SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_SHIFT                    7
#define SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF(x)                       (((uint32_t)(((uint32_t)(x))<<SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_SHIFT))&SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_MASK)



extern uint32_t __vector_table[];
SCB_VTOR = (uint32_t)__vector_table;
```

in my main.c file.

and I have my __vector_table in the interrupt section of linker description file as follows:

```
MEMORY
{
  m_interrupts  (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00002000, LENGTH = 0xC0   /*192 Bytes*/
  ....
  ....
  ....
  ....

 .interrupts :
  {
    __vector_table = .;             
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.vectortable)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } > m_interrupts
```

When an interrupt comes, since I loaded the register SCB_VTOR to the address of __vector_table, it will point to current location of vector table right?? What is the meaning of `SCB_VTOR = (uint32_t)__vector_table;` Is my `SCB_VTOR` pointing to the address `0x00002000` line of code? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `__vector_table` is defined in the linker control file, hence it is part of the implementation, not the application code with regard to the C standard. Long story short: it's fine (and common).

Comment: Vector table of _what_ MCU, more specifically? It would be helpful to know the exact part used. And why are you trying to relocate the vector table? Writing some manner of bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__vector_table` contains the address when it was included in the linker script (`__vector_table = .;` means to get the value of the current address, that is, if the previous sections occupy 8kB, `__vector_table` will contain the next address).

Yes, `SCB_VTOR` contains the address `0x00002000`, given that the section `interrupts` stars in `0x00002000`, and according to the linker script, the first thing to do is get the address.

Bear in mind that some CPUs/MCUs have a fixed vector table, and it starts in a specific register.